# Adding all files listed as to commit in the gitignore file at once in GitHub for Windows

Tags: windows-7, git, github

When committing in [GitHub for Windows](https://windows.github.com/), is there any way to add all files listed as to commit in the .gitignore file at once?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is currently no way to add all files listed as to commit in the .gitignore file at once in GitHub for Windows.